# Dynamic Image to Crystal report Without using database

Tags: asp.net

The following is my requirement:

I have an image file called `"Test.jpg"` in a path say `c:\`. I'll change that image every one minute, but with same path and same file name. I want that image to be loaded in *crystal report* (Business objects) and that image should refresh according to the image change.

How would I do this?